# C# Custom Object List- Find Objects Using SQL Like Statement

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I used to have a datatable and I would query this using:

```
 rows = dtpc.Select("POSTCODE LIKE '" + postcodeID + "%'");
```

This would return many rows which I could then delete from the datatable.

Now I am using a customerobjects List instead of the datatable.

```
 [Serializable]
    public class CUSTOMEROBJECT
    {
        public string Rep_code { get; set; }

        public string Int_rep_hou { get; set; }

        public string Int_rep_key { get; set; }

        public string Fullname { get; set; }

        public string Custcode { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        public string Address3 { get; set; }

        public string Postcode { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string Telephone { get; set; }

        public double Lat { get; set; }

        public double Lng { get; set; }

        public string County { get; set; }
    }
```

How would I find a selection of customer objects using something similar to the LIKE statement I used above?

Comment: `list.Where(w => w.Postcode.StartsWith(postcodeID)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ`

```
customerList.Where(c => c.Postcode.StartsWith(postcodeID.ToString()));
```

Comment: thank you, however how would I go about this: If the postcodeid is 'BW' it would return all BW postcodes which is great. But what if the postcode id was just 'B' or a single character, I would only want to return 'B1'B2'B3'B4' ect and not the 'BW'.

Comment: Use substring to extract the first character of the postcodeid and use that instead of postcodeid in the linq query

Comment: Hi,yes i can get the first character but using .Startwith will return e.g B1,B2,B3 and also BW BG BH etc. I only want to return B1,B2,B3 thanks